# unpack the list created by pool map

Tags: python, pool

I have a code that I wanted to parallelize

```
final_list = []
for module_packages in module_packages_list:
    for module_package in module_packages:
        final_list += parse_jdk_package(module_package)
```

It creates the list of lists -> basically structure `[[items],[items]]`

I wanted to parallelize the second loop using `Pool`.
I did it like this

```
for module_packages in module_packages_list:
    with Pool(4) as p:
        final_list += p.map(parse_jdk_package, module_packages)
```

While it indeed became faster, it creates the additional list over the list of lists. How to unpack it? I was trying to do it like this

```
final_list += zip(*p.map(parse_jdk_package, module_packages))
```

But it turned it into `[([` instead of the regular result `[[[` that I get from the `map`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
def compute_pool(n, f, m):
    with Pool(n) as p:
        return p.map(f, m)

final_list = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        compute_pool(4, parse_jdk_package, module_packages) for module_packages in module_packages_list
    )
```

But it would be better to compute everything with the same pool:

```
with Pool(4) as p:
    final_list = p.map(
        parse_jdk_package,
        itertools.chain.from_iterable(module_packages_list)
    )
```

Comment: how to use the `final_list` then? I was trying to iterate over it `for line in final_list` but it fails with `pool not running`

Comment: I presume processing `final_list`should be run inside `with` block?

Comment: @lapots, I change it, I realized you wanted something different

Comment: in your first example with `compute_pool` I presume n is a parameter for Pool, f is parse_jdk_package and *args is module_packages?

Comment: BTW if I were to store `final_list` to file, should I wrap `with open(f...)` over `with pool` or it is better to do that separately?

Comment: I would do it outside without wrapping

Comment: BTW it still returns list of lists of lists with `[[[`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201886/discussion-between-netwave-and-lapots).